# MySQL Workbench RoR Migration Exporter

Tags: python, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I created plugin for MySQL Workbench that allows you to export an ER Diagram to RoR migration files. I would like to know if any other developers appreciate it.

export-rails-4-migrations_grt.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# MySQL Workbench module
# <description>
# Written in MySQL Workbench 6.3.6

from wb import *
import grt
import sys
import mforms
import datetime
import inflection

ModuleInfo = DefineModule(name='generateRailsMigration',
                         author='Bob Dill',
                          version='0.1')

@ModuleInfo.plugin('wb.util.generateRailsMigration',
                   caption='Export Rails 4.2 Migration',
                   input=[wbinputs.currentCatalog()],
                   groups=['Catalog/Utilities', 'Menu/Catalog'])

@ModuleInfo.export(grt.INT, grt.classes.db_Catalog)

def generateRailsMigration(catalog):
    try:
        exporter = Exporter(catalog)

    except ExportError as e:
        e.show()

    return 0

###############################################################################
#
# Common data structures not supplied by python, but needed for this project
#
###############################################################################
class LinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, value, prev = None, next = None):
        if (prev):
            prev.next = self
        self.prev = prev
        self.value = value
        if (next):
            next.prev = self
        self.next = next

class LinkedListIter:
    def __init__(self, startNode):
        self.node = startNode

    def next(self):
        if(self.node == None):
            raise StopIteration()

        value = self.node.value
        self.node = self.node.next

        return value


    def prev(self):
        if(self.node == None):
            raise StopIteration()

        value = self.node.value
        self.node = self.node.prev

        return value

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.begin()

    def begin(self):
        return LinkedListIter(self.head)

    def end(self):
        return LinkedListIter(self.tail)

    def toString(self):
        itr = self.begin()
        ret = "["
        try:
            value = itr.next()
            ret += str(value)
            while(True):
                value = itr.next()
                ret += ", " + str(value)
        except StopIteration, si:
            ret += "]" 
            return ret

    def __str__(self):
        return self.toString()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.toString()

    def __len__(self):
        return self.count

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return len(self)

    def push_back(self, value):
        if(self.tail):
            node = LinkedListNode(value, self.tail)
            self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail = LinkedListNode(value)
            self.head = self.tail
        self.count += 1

    def push_front(self, value):
        if (self.head):
            node = LinkedListNode(value, None, self.head)
            self.head = node
        else:
            self.head = LinkedListNode(value)
            self.tail = self.head
        self.count += 1

    def back(self):
        return self.tail.value

    def front(self):
        return self.head.value

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.count == 0

    def pop_back(self):
        value = self.tail.value
        self.tail = self.tail.prev
        if (self.tail == None):
            self.head = None
        self.count -= 1
        return value

    def pop_front(self):
        value = self.head.value
        self.head = self.head.next
        if(self.head == None):
            self.tail = None
        self.count -= 1
        return value

    def display(self):
        node = self.head
        while(node):
            print(node.value)
            node = node.next

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.linkedList = LinkedList()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.linkedList.toString()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.linkedList.toString()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.linkedList)

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return len(self.linkedList)

    def push_back(self, value):
        self.linkedList.push_back(value)

    def back(self):
        return self.linkedList.back()

    def pop_back(self):
        return self.linkedList.pop_back()

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.linkedList = LinkedList()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.linkedList.toString()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.linkedList.toString()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.linkedList)

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return len(self.linkedList)

    def push_back(self, value):
        self.linkedList.push_back(value)

    def front(self):
        return self.linkedList.front()

    def pop_front(self):
        return self.linkedList.pop_front()

###############################################################################
#
# The following defines classes used to copy and manipulate the read-only
# tables, columns and foreign keys given by MySQL Workbench. To differentiate
# between these classes and the MySQL workbench classes...
#
###############################################################################

class ExportError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, title, message):
        self.title = title
        self.message = message

    def show(self):
        return mforms.Utilities.show_error(
            self.title,
            self.message,
            'OK', "", "")

tableLookup = {}
columnLookup = {}

class Column:
    def __init__(self, wbColumn):
        self.__wbColumn = wbColumn

    def getAutoIncrement(self):
        return self.__wbColumn.autoIncrement

    # Return the name of the column.
    def getName(self):
        return self.__wbColumn.name

    def getCamelizedName(self, plural = False):
        name = self.__wbColumn.name
        name = inflection.camelize(name)
        if (plural):
            name = inflection.pluralize(name)
        return name

    def getUnderscoredName(self, plural = False):
        name = self.__wbColumn.name
        name = inflection.underscore(name)
        if (plural):
            name = inflection.pluralize(name)
        return name

    def getSymbolName(self):
        return ":" + self.__wbColumn.name

    # Returns the columns type, INT, CHAR, VARCHAR, etc. 
    def getType(self):
        if (self.__wbColumn.simpleType):
            return self.__wbColumn.simpleType.name
        return self.__wbColumn.userType.actualType.name

    # If the type is a char or varchar, this function returns the number of
    # characters that can be stored in the column
    def getLength(self):
        return self.__wbColumn.length

    # The maximum number of digits in a decimal value
    def getPrecision(self):
        return self.__wbColumn.precision

    # Returns the number of digits after the decimal point in a DECIMAL 
    # column type
    def getScale(self):
        return self.__wbColumn.scale

    def isNotNull(self):
        return self.__wbColumn.isNotNull

    def defaultValue(self):
        if (self.__wbColumn.defaultValueIsNull):
            return "nil"
        return self.__wbColumn.defaultValue


class ForeignKey:
    def __init__(self, wbfk):
        # Ensure that the name ends with _id
        self.__wbfk = wbfk

    def getName(self):
        return self.__wbfk.name

    def referencedTable(self):
        return getTable(self.__wbfk.referencedTable)

    def getOwner(self):
        return getTable(self.__wbfk.owner)

    def numColumns(self):
        return len(self.__wbfk.columns)

    def getFirstColumn(self):
        return getColumn(self.__wbfk.columns[0])

    def getFirstReferencedColumn(self):
        return getColumn(self.__wbfk.columns[0])

    def hasStandardName(self):
        stdName = inflection.underscore(self.__wbfk.referencedTable.name) + "_id"
        colName = self.__wbfk.columns[0].name
        return colName == stdName


class Table:
    def __init__(self, wbTable):
        # Notes
        # Ensure a standard primary key (id integer auto_increment)

        # Store a reference to the wbTable
        self.wbTable = wbTable
        # Define a list of columns.
        self.columns = []
        # Define a list of foreign keys that were removed to prevent cyclic dependencies
        self.resolved_fks = []

        # For each wb column, create and store the exporter column
        for wbColumn in wbTable.columns:
            column = getColumn(wbColumn)
            self.columns.append(column)

        self.assignPrimaryKey()

    def assignPrimaryKey(self):
        if (not self.wbTable.primaryKey):
            self.primaryKey = None
        else:
            if (len(self.wbTable.primaryKey.columns) > 1):
                raise ExportError("Composite Primary Key Error", "Table " + self.wbTable.name + " contains a composite primary key. Composite keys are currently not supported by rails and this application. Use a surragate key instead and retry exporting.")
            else:
                self.primaryKey = getColumn(self.wbTable.primaryKey.columns[0].referencedColumn)
                if (self.primaryKey.getName() != "id"):
                    print("Got here")
                    raise ExportError("Non-standard Primary Key", "Table " + self.wbTable.name + " uses a non-standard name for its primary key. Rename the key to 'id' and retry exporting.")
                if (self.primaryKey.getType() != "INT"): 
                    raise ExportError("Non-standard Primary Key", "Table " + self.wbTable.name + " uses a primary key that is not an integer. Change the keys type to integer and retry exporting.")
                if (not self.primaryKey.getAutoIncrement()):
                    raise ExportError("Non-standard Primary Key", "Table " + self.wbTable.name + " uses a primary key that is not an auto-incrementing integer. Make the key auto-incrementing, and retry export.")

    def getIndices(self):
        return self.wbTable.indices

    def addForeignKeys(self):
        # Create a list to store the foreign keys.  
        self.foreignKeys = []

        # Loop through all the wb foreign keys and create a list
        # exporter foreign keys from them.
        for wbfk in self.wbTable.foreignKeys:
            if (len(wbfk.columns) != 1):
                raise ExportError("Non-standard Foreign Key", "Table " + self.wbTable.name + " uses a foreign key that does not contain exactly one column. Composite foreign keys are not supported. Change your design to follow the rails convention and retry export.")
            if (wbfk.columns[0].name[-3:] != "_id"):
                raise ExportError("Non-standard Foreign Key", "Table " + self.wbTable.name + " uses a foreign key that is named incorrectly. Ensure that the foreign key ends with '_id', and retry export.")
            fk = ForeignKey(wbfk)
            self.foreignKeys.append(fk)

    def getName(self):
        return self.wbTable.name

    def getClassName(self, plural):
        name = self.wbTable.name
        name = inflection.camelize(name)
        if (plural):
            name = inflection.pluralize(name)
        return name

    def getSymbolName(self, plural):
        name = self.wbTable.name
        name = inflection.underscore(name)
        if (plural):
            name = inflection.pluralize(name)
        return ":" + name

    def getDependencies(self):
        # Create a list to hold the tables this table is
        # dependent upon.
        tables = []

        # Loop through all the foreign keys and create a list
        # of the tables they reference.
        for fk in self.foreignKeys:
            table = fk.referencedTable()
            tables.append(table)

        # Return the tables.
        return tables

    def removeDependency(self, table):
        # Create a copy of the list 
        for fk in list(self.foreignKeys):
            if (fk.referencedTable() == table):
                self.foreignKeys.remove(fk)
                self.resolved_fks.append(fk)

    def hasStandardPrimaryKey(self):
        pk = self.primaryKey
        if (pk == None):
            return False

        return (pk.getName()) == 'id' and (pk.getAutoIncrement() == 1) and (pk.getType() == "INT")

class Tables:
    # This function recreates the structure of the directed graph formed by
    # the tables and their connections via foreign keys. A time consuming task.
    def __init__(self, catalog):
        # Define a list of tables.
        self.__tables = []

        # Create and store workbench tables as an exporter tables.
        for wbTable in catalog.schemata[0].tables:
            table = getTable(wbTable)
            self.__tables.append(table)

        # Connect the tables
        for table in self.__tables:
            table.addForeignKeys()

    const_white = 0
    const_grey = 1
    const_black = 2

    # Generate a hash to mark nodes as visited or not visited
    def __createColorHash(self):
        h = {}
        for table in self.__tables:
            h[table] = Tables.const_white
        return h

    def topSortUtil(self, startTable, colorHash, orderQueue):
        pathStack = Stack()
        pathStack.push_back(startTable)

        while(pathStack):
            table = pathStack.back()

            # if this is true, all the children have been visited,
            # mark the table as black, remove it from the search path stack,
            # and add it to the orderQueue
            if(colorHash[table] == Tables.const_grey):
                colorHash[table] = Tables.const_black
                pathStack.pop_back()
                orderQueue.push_back(table)
                continue

            # Mark the table as being explored
            colorHash[table] = Tables.const_grey

            # Push unvisitted adjacent tables onto the stack.
            dependencies = table.getDependencies();
            for dependent in dependencies:
                if(colorHash[dependent] == Tables.const_white):
                    pathStack.push_back(dependent)
                if(colorHash[dependent] == Tables.const_grey):
                    if (table != dependent):
                        table.removeDependency(dependent)

    def topSort(self):
        colorHash = self.__createColorHash()
        orderQueue = Queue()

        for table in self.__tables:
            if(colorHash[table] == Tables.const_white):
                self.topSortUtil(table, colorHash, orderQueue)

        return orderQueue

def getColumn(wbColumn):
    if wbColumn in columnLookup:
        return columnLookup[wbColumn]

    column = Column(wbColumn)
    columnLookup[wbColumn] = column
    return column

def getTable(wbTable):
    if wbTable in tableLookup:
        return tableLookup[wbTable]

    table = Table(wbTable)
    tableLookup[wbTable] = table
    return table

###############################################################################
#
# Classes that generate the files and write the DDL in Rail's migration file
# format.
#
###############################################################################


# Using a composite pattern
class SourceComponent(object):
    def __init__(self, name = None):
        self.components = []
        self.name = name

    def add(self, component):
        self.components.append(component)

    # Calls write for 
    def write(self, toFile, indent = 0):
        for component in self.components:
            component.write(toFile, indent)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.components[key]

    # Returns the number of components
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.components)

    def find(name):
        if (self.name == name):
            return self

        for comp in self.components:
            ret = comp.find(name)
            if (ret):
                return ret;

        return None

class SCLine(SourceComponent):
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line

    def write(self, toFile, indent):
        toFile.write("  " * indent + self.line + "\n")

class SCFunc(SCLine):
    def __init__(self, funcName, *args):
        line = funcName
        argLen = len(args)
        if (argLen > 0):
            for i in range(0, argLen - 1):
                line += " " + args[i] + ","
            line += " " + args[argLen - 1]

        self.line = line

# :limit - Requests a maximum column length. This is number of characters for :string and :text columns and number of bytes for :binary and :integer columns.
# :default - The column‘s default value. Use nil for NULL.
# :null - Allows or disallows NULL values in the column. This option could have been named :null_allowed.
# :precision - Specifies the precision for a :decimal column.
# :scale - Specifies the scale for a :decimal column.
class SCColumn(SCFunc):
    def __init__(self, column):
        name = column.getName()

        # Special column names that corrospond directly to function in Rails.
        if (name == "timestamps"):
            super(SCColumn, self).__init__("t.timestamps", "null:false")
            return

        # Retrieve the columns simple type
        colType = column.getType()
        funcName = None
        args = [column.getSymbolName()]

        # Thanks to
        # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889048/is-there-documentation-for-the-rails-column-types
        if (colType == "VARCHAR"):
            funcName = "t.string"
            length = column.getLength()
            if (length != 255):
                args.append("limit:" + str(length))
        # MySQL workbench ignores the precision on tinyint's. A shame considering TINYINT(1)
        # is a synonym for a boolean, and TINYINT(2) or more is not necessarily treated
        # as a boolean. For now, I will treat any TINYINT as boolean. (as safe default?)
        elif (colType == "TINYINT"):
            funcName = "t.boolean"
        elif (colType == "SMALLINT"):
            funcName = "t.integer"
            args.append("limit: 2")
        elif (colType == "MEDIUMINT"):
            funcName = "t.integer"
            args.append("limit: 3")
        elif (colType == "INT"):
            funcName = "t.integer"
        elif (colType == "BIGINT"):
            funcName = "t.integer"
            args.append("limit: 8")
        elif (colType == "FLOAT"):
            funcName = "t.float"
        elif (colType == "TEXT"):
            funcName = "t.text"
            length = column.getLength();
            if (length != -1):
                args.append("limit: " + str(length))
        elif (colType == "DECIMAL"):
            funcName = "t.decimal"
            precision = column.getPrecision()
            if (precision != -1):
                args.append("precision:" + str(precision))
            scale = column.getScale()
            if (scale != -1):
                args.append("scale:" + str(scale))
        elif (colType == "BLOB"):
            funcName = "t.binary"
            length = column.getLength()
            if (length != -1):
                args.append("limit: " + str(length))
        elif (colType == "DATE"):
            funcName = "t.date"
        elif (colType == "TIME"):
            funcName = "t.time"
        elif (colType == "DATETIME"):
            funcName = "t.datetime"
        elif (colType == "TIMESTAMP"):
            funcName = "t.timestamp"

        if not funcName:
            raise ExportError("Unsupported Column Type", "Columns of type " + colType + " are not supported. Change the column to a supported type and retry export.")

        if (column.isNotNull()):
            args.append("null:false")

        defaultValue = column.defaultValue()
        if (defaultValue != ''):
            args.append("default:" + defaultValue)

        print(colType)
        print(args)
        super(SCColumn, self).__init__(funcName, *args)


class SCBlock(SourceComponent):
    def __init__(self, topLine = None, bottomLine = "end"):
        super(SCBlock, self).__init__()
        self.topLine = topLine
        self.bottomLine = bottomLine

    def write(self, toFile, indent):
        if (self.topLine):
            line = SCLine(self.topLine)
            line.write(toFile, indent)
        super(SCBlock, self).write(toFile, indent + 1)
        if (self.bottomLine):
            line = SCLine(self.bottomLine)
            line.write(toFile, indent)


class SCClass(SCBlock):
    def __init__(self, className, baseClassName = None):
        topLine = None
        if (baseClassName):
            topLine = "class %s < %s" % (className, baseClassName)
        else:
            topLine = "class %s" % (className)
        super(SCClass, self).__init__(topLine)

class SCFuncBlock(SCBlock):
    def __init__(self, funcName, blockVar, *args):
        topLine = funcName
        argLen = len(args)
        if (argLen > 0):
            for i in range(0, argLen - 1):
                topLine += " " + args[i] + ","
            topLine += " " + args[argLen - 1]

        topLine += " do |" + blockVar + "|"
        super(SCFuncBlock, self).__init__(topLine)

class SCCreateTableBlock(SCFuncBlock):
    def __init__(self, table):
        tblName = table.getSymbolName(True)
        if (table.primaryKey):
            super(SCCreateTableBlock, self).__init__("create_table", "t", tblName)
        else:
            super(SCCreateTableBlock, self).__init__("create_table", "t", tblName, "id: false")

# Function Declation Component
class SCFuncDec(SCBlock):
    def __init__(self, funcName):
        topLine = "def " + funcName
        super(SCFuncDec, self).__init__(topLine)

###############################################################################
#
# This section contains classes that represent entire files.
#
###############################################################################

class MultiValuedParam(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.numParams = 0
        self.params = ""

    def add(self, param):
        if (self.numParams == 0):
            self.params = str(param)
        else:
            self.params += ", " + str(param)

        self.numParams += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return self.params

    def __len__(self):
        return self.numParams

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.numParams

# This class simplifies creating the column length parameter
class ColLengthParam(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstColumn = None;
        self.firstLength = 0;
        self.numColumns = 0;
        self.params = "";

    def add(self, column, length):
        if (length == 0):
            return;

        if (self.numColumns == 0):
            self.params =  "length: " + str(length)
            self.firstLength = length
            self.firstColumn = column
        elif (self.numColumns == 1):
            self.params = "length: {" + self.firstColumn + ": " + str(self.firstLength)
            self.params += ", " + column + ": " + str(length)
        else:
            self.params += ", " + column + ": " + str(length)

        self.numColumns += 1 

    def __str__(self):
        if (self.numColumns < 2):
            return self.params
        else:
            return self.params + "}"

    def __len__(self):
        return self.numColumns

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.numColumns


class MigrationFile(SourceComponent):
    def __init__(self, table):
        super(MigrationFile, self).__init__()
        clsName = table.getClassName(True)

        cls = SCClass("Create" + clsName, "ActiveRecord::Migration")
        func = SCFuncDec("change")
        block = SCCreateTableBlock(table)

        columnSection = SourceComponent()
        # Contains all but the resolved foreign keys
        belongsToSection = SourceComponent()
        # Used for foreign keys that have non-standard name
        addFkSection = SourceComponent()
        addIndexSection = SourceComponent()

        self.addColumns(table, columnSection)
        self.addForeignKeys(table, belongsToSection, addFkSection)
        self.addIndices(table, addIndexSection)

        # Assemble the components
        block.add(columnSection)
        block.add(belongsToSection)
        func.add(block)
        func.add(addIndexSection)
        func.add(addFkSection)
        cls.add(func)

        self.add(cls)

    def addIndices(self, table, addIndexSection):
        tblName = table.getSymbolName(True)
        indices = table.getIndices()
        for index in indices:
            if (index.indexType == "PRIMARY"):
                continue

            args = [tblName]


            numColumns = len(index.columns)
            # Should an error or warning be displayed here?
            if (numColumns == 0):
                continue
            elif (numColumns == 1):
                column = index.columns[0]
                colName = column.referencedColumn.name
                args.append(":" + colName)
                if (column.columnLength != 0):
                    args.append("length: " + str(column.columnLength))
            else:
                colNameParam = MultiValuedParam()
                colLengthParam = MultiValuedParam()
                # Loop through the columns gathering the necessary parameters
                for column in index.columns:
                    colName = column.referencedColumn.name
                    colNameParam.add(":" + colName)
                    if (column.columnLength != 0):
                        colLengthParam.add(colName + ": " + str(column.columnLength))

                args.append("[" + str(colNameParam) + "]")
                if (colLengthParam):
                    args.append("length: {" + str(colLengthParam) + "}")

            # Add the type if necessary
            if (index.indexType == "UNIQUE"):
                args.append("unique:true")
            elif (index.indexType == "FULLTEXT"):
                args.append("type: :fulltext")

            # Uncomment if you want to preserve the index names
            # args.append("name:'%s'" % (index.name))
            addIndexSection.add(SCFunc("add_index", *args))


    # Plain columns are columns that are not primary keys or foreign keys
    def getPlainColumns(self, table):
        # Generates a list of columns that are not foreign keys
        columns = list(table.columns)
        fks = table.foreignKeys
        for fk in fks:
            col = fk.getFirstColumn()
            columns.remove(col)

        if (table.primaryKey):
            # This handles the case when the primary key is also a foreign key.
            try:
                columns.remove(table.primaryKey)
            except ValueError:
                pass


        return columns

    def addColumns(self, table, section):
        columns = self.getPlainColumns(table)

        # Add the columns to the sec
        for column in columns:
            section.add(SCColumn(column))

    def addForeignKeys(self, table, belongsToSec, addFkSec):
        tblName = table.getSymbolName(True)
        fks = table.foreignKeys

        for fk in fks:
            column = fk.getFirstColumn()
            colName = ":" + column.getName()
            args = [colName[:-3]]

            if (fk.hasStandardName()):
                args.append("foreign_key:true")
            else:
                refName = fk.referencedTable().getSymbolName(True)
                args.append("references: " + refName)

                # Add function to section that adds foreign keys
                func = SCFunc("add_foreign_key", tblName, refName, "column: " + colName)
                addFkSec.add(func)

            if (column.isNotNull()):
                args.append("null:false")

            belongsToSec.add(SCFunc("t.belongs_to", *args))

            args = []

class ResolvedFile(SourceComponent):
    def __init__(self, tables):
        super(ResolvedFile, self).__init__()
        cls = SCClass("AddResolvedForeignKeys", "ActiveRecord::Migration")
        func = SCFuncDec("change")

        cls.add(func)

        # This variable 
        self.resolved = False

        for table in tables:
            fks = table.resolved_fks
            if (fks):
                self.resolved = True
                tableName = table.getSymbolName(True)
                for fk in fks:
                    refName = fk.referencedTable().getSymbolName(True)
                    colName = ":" + fk.getFirstColumn().getName()
                    func.add(SCFunc("add_foreign_key", tableName, refName, "column: " + colName))

        if (self.resolved):
            self.add(cls)


###############################################################################
#
# The class that acutally does the exporting
#
###############################################################################
class Exporter:
    def __init__(self, catalog):
        self.migNum = 0
        self.tables = Tables(catalog)
        self.sortedTables = self.tables.topSort().linkedList

        if self.choosePath():
            self.writeMigrations()
            mforms.Utilities.show_message(
                "Export Successful",
                "The migration files were successfully created and placed in the folder you selected.",
                'OK', "", "")

    def choosePath(self):
        file_chooser = mforms.newFileChooser(None, mforms.OpenDirectory)
        if file_chooser.run_modal() == mforms.ResultOk:
            self.path = file_chooser.get_path()
            return True
        return False

    def genMigrationFileName(self, name):
        tblName = inflection.pluralize(inflection.underscore(name))
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        fileName = '/%s%s%s%s_%s.rb' % (now.strftime('%Y'), now.strftime('%m'), now.strftime('%d'), str(self.migNum).zfill(6), tblName)
        self.migNum += 1
        return fileName

    def writeMigrations(self):
        for table in self.sortedTables:
            self.writeMigration(table)

        self.writeResolved()

    def writeMigration(self, table):
        fileName = self.genMigrationFileName("Create_" + table.getName())
        f = MigrationFile(table)
        self.writeFile(self.path + fileName, f)

    def writeResolved(self):
        fileName = self.genMigrationFileName("AddResolvedForeignKeys")

        f = ResolvedFile(self.sortedTables)
        if (f.resolved):
            self.writeFile(self.path + fileName, f)

    def writeFile(self, path, sc):
        try:
            with open(path, 'w+') as f:
                # Write to the file
                sc.write(f)
        except IOError as e:
            mforms.Utilities.show_error(
            'Save to File',
            'Could not save to file "%s": %s' % (self.path, str(e)),
            'OK')

# generateRailsMigration(grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog)
```

In order to use this plugin, you must install the 'inflection' module for Python via 'pip install inflection' Then in the MySQL Workbench menu go to Scipting -> Install Plugin/Module... Restart MySQL Workbench. Then, create your diagram and export it by selecting Tools -> Catalog -> Export Rails 4.2 Migration from the menu.

Please note that the database must be designed the Rails way. That means no composite primary keys or foreign keys. No primary keys that are not auto-incrementing, integers named 'id,' and finally, foreign keys must end with '_id.' For more information, I put the project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/binarybob0010/Rails-Migration-Exporter).